# Record tf_static with rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, tf-static

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to record all my topics into a bag, running `rosbag record -a`. However, rosbag doesn't record the `/tf_static` topic.
How can I arrange this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/178973/record-tf_static-with-rosbag/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-06-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think rosbag only records topics that are actually publishing messages. From what I can tell, /tf_static is only used by new tf2 publishers, and very few packages currently make use of it.

I would verify that there are messages published on /tf_static before worrying that they're not being recorded.

If you do have a node publishing messages to /tf_static and they're not being recorded, that's probably a bug in rosbag.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0